# RESTful retorna undefined em JS Class

Tags: javascript, api, rest, restful

Estou fazendo alterações no HTML após pegar dados da API do LastFm, trabalhando com class em JS, fazendo as chamadas dos método dentro da própria class, onde o data foi chamado antes, porem esta retorna undefined:

```
    class Tidal{
        constructor(ev){
            this.dom = ev;
            this.data = {};
            this.elements = {};

            this.getInfo();
            console.log(this)
        }

        getInfo(){
            var self = this.data;

            var lastfm = new LastFM({
              apiKey    : '929cfb240401e3f7c1c0cd531aa1939e',
              apiSecret : 'ac2ecff79d5881a1a8e810f249f052df'
            });

            lastfm.artist.getInfo({artist: 'Madeon'}, {success: function(data){
                self.artistInfo = data;
            }, error: function(code, message){
              console.log(code, message);
            }});

            console.log(self.artistInfo, 12345) // retorna undefined
        }
   }
```

Porem quando chamado após o arquivo ser carregado no devTools o método funciona corretamente.

Comment: Me parece ser problema de sincronismo. Veja que vc está chamando a propriedade fora do callback. Fora do callback a propriedade não existe.

Comment: Meu caro, eu acho que o problema é essa chamada do getInfo dentro do constructor. Eu acredito que você não deva invoca-lo ai.